# How to set Zoom Level in android Map v2 on the basis of Kilometers selected by User?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

- I am using a mapview in which by default it shows current location.
- I am using a seekbar to control zoom level based on Kilometers divided into 10,20,30,50...km.
- How to zoom in or zoom out (in Kilometers) map when user touches the seek bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this formula:

```
zoomLevel = 19 - Math.log(altitudeKm * 5.508);
```

It is not going to be 100% accurate since map is 2D representation of 3D world. Thus there is no such thing as 'view altitude'. Anyways I tried to play a bit with it and it looks close enough. :)

Taken from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5454d549-5eeb-43a5-b188-63121d3f0cc1/how-to-set-zoomlevel-for-particular-altitude?forum=bingmaps). Bing maps use the same Mercator projection as android map v2, so basic math should be the same